# Is completeness equivalent to closure in complete metric spaces?

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a *complete metric space* and consider a subset $A \subset X$:

- $A$ closed $\implies$ $A$ complete (I know that)
- **$A$ complete $\stackrel{(?)}{\implies}$ $A$ closed**

I was wondering about the truth of the second implication. If it's true does the following proof is correct?

---

**Proof** (Proof by contrapositive, $\neg A$ closed $\implies \neg A$ complete ):
Take $a \in A' \cap A^c$ (exists since A is not closed, closed sets contains their limit points) 
and consider the following sequence in $A$ such that

$$\large{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in N_{1/n}(a)  }$$

This is a Cauchy sequence in fact $\forall \epsilon>0$ I can set $\large{n_\epsilon := \lceil{\frac{1}{\epsilon}} \rceil}$ to have $d(x_n, x_m)<\epsilon \hspace{4pt} \forall n \ge n_\epsilon$.
But $(x_n)$ does not converge because $a \in A^c. \blacksquare$

**Notations**: with $A'$ I mean the *derived set*; with $N_r(p)$ I mean the *neighbourhood* of $p$ with radius r.

Comment: I think your proof is correct

Comment: you can just notice that a convergent sequence is a cauchy sequence, then you ar done

Comment: @JensRenders ok, it's clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $A $ complete.

let prove that $\bar {A}\subset A $.
take $a\in \bar {A} $.

then
$a=\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n $ with
$a_n\in A $.

$(a_n) $ is Cauchy in $A $ since it converges.

but $A $ is complete then $a\in A $.